# Facing issue with ionic web-socket connection with java socket server

Tags: java, android, sockets, ionic-framework, firewall

I am facing issue with websocket on Ionic 
connection with "ionic serve" working perfect. but when i try with "ionic run android"(which is connected with WiFi) getting below given error.

```
"WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.1.7:8086/wsConn' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"
```

"192.168.1.7" is my server ip address.

I tested server running on window 10 and window server 2012 both.

tried with turning off server firewall also.

Can anyone help me on this ?